# Telegram I need to verify stripe payment after button click

Tags: telegram

Hello stackoverflow so for telegram I have a simple message with a button. Upon button click it is taking me to my stripe url. I want to know how I can handle successful/uncessfull payments after the user has paid. Here is my code so far

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors')
const axios = require("axios");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const invoiceDescription = require('./constants');

const { TOKEN, SERVER_URL, BOTTOKEN } = process.env;
const TELEGRAM_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}`;
const URI = `/webhook/${TOKEN}`;
const WEBHOOK_URL = SERVER_URL + URI;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const init = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${TELEGRAM_API}/setWebhook?url=${WEBHOOK_URL}`);
  console.log(res.data);
};

app.get("/payment", async (req, res) => {
    alert("Hello world");
})

app.post(URI, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
  let text = "", chatId = "", userObjectForTable = {}; 
  if(req.body.message?.chat?.id && req.body.message?.text && req.body.message?.text === "Start"){
        chatId = req.body.message.chat.id;
        text = invoiceDescription;
        const message = await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendMessage`, {
            chat_id: chatId,
            text: text,
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard: [[{
                    text: 'Pay $65.00',
                    web_app: {url: 'https://buy.stripe.com/test_14kbKj3Gd0AGeRi' }
                }]]
            }
        });
        console.log("test message is", message)
    }
  return res.send();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5050, async () => {
  console.log(" app running on port", process.env.PORT || 5050);
  await init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen for the update `message.successful_payment`, when it arrives it means that the payment has been made successfully

Source:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#8-checkout